# Get word from an id in a web page in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

i want python to read a specific word from a website,
i searched in urllib and bs4 but i didn't find any example for something that can do this

example for what i want:

on this page https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=weather%20in%20egypt&gws_rd=ssl

i want python to read:

```
>>>id = wob_tm
>>>print 'weather is ' + id 
weather is 16
```

is it possible ?

Comment: Google really doesn't want you to do that; why don't you use some open weather API instead?

Comment: it's just an example...

Comment: `soup.select("#myid")`

Comment: it worked, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using an API if you want this information. But if you just want one piece of data from the page, and you already have the HTML response in a variable, nothing wrong with using a simple regex (rather than parsing the whole page):

`id="wob_tm"[^>]*>([^<]+)`

The value will be found in group 1 of the match.
[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/hA8sV1/3).